# How to implement HAPI FHIR resource dao?

Tags: java, mysql, hapi, hl7-fhir

I am new to HAPI FHIR. Everything goes alright, including the Web UI. I even success to configure to create schema in mysql database. However, in the last step, something error happened and hard to me to fix.

This is my servlet:

```
        super.initialize();
    myAppCtx = ContextLoaderListener.getCurrentWebApplicationContext();
    FhirVersionEnum fhirVersion = FhirVersionEnum.DSTU2;
    setFhirContext(new FhirContext(fhirVersion));

    // Resource
    IFhirResourceDao<Patient> patientDAO = myAppCtx.getBean("myPatientDaoDstu2", IFhirResourceDao.class);
    JpaResourceProviderDstu2<Patient> patientProvider = new JpaResourceProviderDstu2<Patient>(patientDAO); 
    List<IResourceProvider> resourceProviders = new ArrayList<IResourceProvider>();
    resourceProviders.add(patientProvider);
    setResourceProviders(resourceProviders);

    // System
    Object systemProvider;
    systemProvider = myAppCtx.getBean("mySystemProviderDstu2", JpaSystemProviderDstu2.class);
    setPlainProviders(systemProvider);


    // Conformance
    IFhirSystemDao<Bundle, MetaDt> systemDao = myAppCtx.getBean("mySystemDaoDstu2", IFhirSystemDao.class);
    JpaConformanceProviderDstu2 confProvider = new JpaConformanceProviderDstu2(this, systemDao,
            myAppCtx.getBean(DaoConfig.class));
    confProvider.setImplementationDescription("HBI Solutions");
    setServerConformanceProvider(confProvider);
```

web.xml is here

```
<web-app>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
        <param-value>
    org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            com.hbisolutions.www.fhir.config.FhirServerConfig
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
            <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>com.hbisolutions.www.fhir.config.FhirTesterConfig</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

However, when I go to the Web UI and search a patient, error shows that

```
Error: HTTP 400 : Invalid request: The FHIR endpoint on this server does not know how to handle GET operation[Patient] with parameters [[_pretty]]
```

Any idea how to solve this? And BTW, do I need to add ever resource type to the `resourceProviders`?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally got things working. It turns out that I do not need to implement each resource by myself. There is a bean which contains all the resource types.

try replacing

```
IFhirResourceDao<Patient> patientDAO = myAppCtx.getBean("myPatientDaoDstu2", IFhirResourceDao.class);
JpaResourceProviderDstu2<Patient> patientProvider = new JpaResourceProviderDstu2<Patient>(patientDAO); 
List<IResourceProvider> resourceProviders = new ArrayList<IResourceProvider>();
resourceProviders.add(patientProvider);
setResourceProviders(resourceProviders);
```

with

```
    String resourceProviderBeanName = "myResourceProvidersDstu2";
    List<IResourceProvider> beans = myAppCtx.getBean(resourceProviderBeanName, List.class);
    setResourceProviders(beans);
```